# sort ascending with ksort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array:

```
$optionen_kosten = array(
    "option_5" => array(
        'monthly' => 2,
        'setup' => 5
    ),
    "option_3" => array(
        'monthly' => 2,
        'setup' => 5
    ),
    "option_1" => array(
        'monthly' => 2,
        'setup' => 5
    ),
    "option_6" => array(
        'monthly' => 2,
        'setup' => 5
    ),
    "option_8" => array(
        'monthly' => 2,
        'setup' => 5
    ),
    "option_10" => array(
        'monthly' => 2,
        'setup' => 5
    ),
    "option_2" => array(
        'monthly' => 2,
        'setup' => 5
    ),
    "option_4" => array(
        'monthly' => 2,
        'setup' => 5
    ),
    "option_7" => array(
        'monthly' => 2,
        'setup' => 5
    ),
    "option_9" => array(
        'monthly' => 2,
        'setup' => 5
    )
);
```

Now, I want to sort the key of that array ascending (`option_1`, `option_2`...)

I tried it with [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) but it does not work perfectly:

```
option_1
option_10
option_2
option_3
option_4
option_5
option_6
option_7
option_8
option_9
```

I want `option_10` to be the last one. Maybe with [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)?

**PHP Version: 5.3.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want "natural sort" and you can add that to `ksort` directly (in php 5.4+):

```
ksort($optionen_kosten, SORT_NATURAL);
var_dump($optionen_kosten);
```

See the manual on [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) for more details on the optional parameter values.

A [working example](https://eval.in/518792).

For an older version of php you could use [`uksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php).

That would be something like:

```
uksort($optionen_kosten, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a, $b);
});
var_dump($optionen_kosten);
```

[An example](https://eval.in/518803).

Comment: Thanks. This does not seem to work with PHP 5.3. Is there another solution?

Comment: @Vince Yes, it is php 5.4+. The support for 5.3 ended in August 2014 so you should seriously consider upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: Yes, that would be the best. But for the moment, I have to stay on 5.3. The server is not accessible from outside.